# Jhipster4, Angular2: How include static image in html

Tags: jhipster

Could you help me with including static image in html template.

I generated project using jhipster generator (chosen Angular 2) and now I'm trying to include static image in html-template of component (for example for *NavbarComponent* into *navbar.component.html*). I inserted tag image into navbar.component.html

```
<img src="url" />
```

My image is placed into webapp/content/images/staticimage.jpg (this folder containts logo-hipster.png also). What do I have to place instead of url in img tag to see my image?

P.S. the inital structure of generated project wasn't changed.

Comment: Which version are you using? There was a fix for this: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5333

Comment: Yes, your assumption was right. My project was generated by generator-jhispster with version 4.0.8 where webpack wasn't setuped properly for my case. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was related to version of generator-jhispter (the version was 4.0.8 for my case), where webpack config wasn't set properly.

After upgrade of generator-jhipster (it's 4.3.0) the issue has gone off. 
As I understood this issue also might will be fixed if you change in webpack.common.js next rule

```
{
   test: /\.html$/,
   loader: 'raw-loader',
   exclude: ['./src/main/webapp/index.html']
},
```

New version of generated project brought me the next:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'html-loader',
  options: {
       minimize: true,
       caseSensitive: true,
       removeAttributeQuotes:false,
       minifyJS:false,
       minifyCSS:false
   },
   exclude: ['./src/main/webapp/index.html']
},
```

And also you have to check out there is 'html-loader' in our devDependencies of package.json.

And now tag `<img src="../../../content/images/staticimage.jpg">` works properly.