# jHipster issue with image

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

I am trying to load an image. The source should be an attribute of an object. It is something like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objects">
   <img src="{{object.imagePath}}">
</div>
```

But the image is not found. However if I put the same path, directly into the img tag like this :

```
<img src="../../content/images/myObjectImage.png"/>
```

It works. Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Which version of JHipster?

Comment: If you have wrong path inside `object.imagePath` of course the image is not found. Check your path. What is the result of `console.log(object.imagePath);`?

Comment: From yo-rc file : "jhipsterVersion": "4.1.1"

Comment: Problem is not the path, but using an attribute. For example :  I try to put a string imgPath into my component with value "../../content/images/tim.png" and put <img [src]="imgPath"/> or <img src="imgPath"/>  in my view, it doesn't work. Only <img src="../../content/images/tim.png"> works

Comment: When using the direct path, it seems like the image is copied into target/www with a base64 name. Then if I inspect my web page, the image src is the base64 image. But if I use an attribute, the image is not copied and the src is still the path specified into my code

Comment: Seems to me like the binding is not working check this **https://plnkr.co/edit/FcMa3Ic15TWZKATas6Dg?p=preview**. Do you have any errors in the console ? Check what do you have in the src attribute of your images via developer tools and report

Comment: In your plunker, you are using image from another website. If I do this, it works. But this is not what I am trying to do. No error in the console. To test, I have two img tag. One where i set my src like this : <img src="../../content/images/tim.png">, the developer tools then tell me src="a30deb26b4eb1521433021e326cbcc2c.png". It is the generated base64 image on target/www. And one img tag like this : <img src="{{imgPath}}"/> where imgPath = ../../content/images/tim.png, the developer tools tell me src="../../content/images/tim.png".

Comment: I don't have any experience with `jhipster` but it looks like it is doing some stuff behind the scenes and when you bind image with angular it still doesn't see the path to the image and it can't do those stuff ... Try playing with the path. Can you access your images like this **yourdomain.com/path/to/img.pgn** ?

Comment: Have you checked you have not the same problem as here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792796/jhipster4-angular2-how-include-static-image-in-html

Comment: Webpack is Ok, HtmlLoader is in my package.json, so I don't think so.

Comment: @codtex I can't access my image with **myDomain.com/pathToImage.png** if I am using an attribute, because the image is not copied to **target/www** folder. Otherwise, if I put the direct path into my img tag (e.g. <img src="path/to/image">), the image is copied into target/www folder and you can access it through **myDomain.com/encodedImageName.png**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I found to make it works was to create an array, then populate it that way :

```
for(let i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
{
    imgUrl[i] = require(object[i].imgUrl);
}
```

Then into the view :

```
<img src="{{imgUrl[i]}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute biding as [src]="..."

```
 <div *ngFor="let object of objects">
  <img [src]="object.imagePath">
 </div>
```

Here is an example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let obj of objects">
        <img [src]="obj.path" width="100px">
       </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  objects = [
    {path: 'http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg'},
     {path: 'http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/02-cat-wants-to-tell-you-photos.jpg'}
    ];
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Even when I try to put a string imgPath into my component with value "../../content/images/tim.png" and put <img [src]="imgPath"/> in my view, it doesn't work. Only <img src="../../content/images/tim.png"> works