# How to include static image in html template?

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

Static images are not displayed in html template.
I'm using `JHipster 4.14.1` - `Angular 5` - webpack 3.10.0

I put my image in this folder : `/webapp/content/images`
I use this tag in html template : `<img scr="../../content/images/hello.png" alt="hello the world">`

My webpack config seems to be ok according this link which describe the same problem.
[Jhipster4, Angular2: How include static image in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792796/jhipster4-angular2-how-include-static-image-in-html)

My "webpack.common.js" file contains :

```
test: /\.html$/,
       loader: 'html-loader',
       options: {
           minimize: true,
           caseSensitive: true,
           removeAttributeQuotes:false,
           minifyJS:false,
           minifyCSS:false
       },
       exclude: ['./src/main/webapp/index.html']
   },
   {
       test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
       loaders: ['file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=content/[hash].[ext]']
   },
```

Generated filenames are hashed. So, I opened each PNG image generated in the folder `target/www/content` and I don't find my image.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Add your static files in src/assets directory. Then you can access to static files

Comment: Like this: src="assets/images/img.png"

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `content` directory from your image path.  To include images in Angular:

```
<img src="../../content/images/hipster.png" alt="Hipster" />
```

Note that the number of `../` to include depends on how many directories deep you are relative to the `content` folder

Webpack hashes the image when compiling the TS and templates, so it will be in `/target/www/content/` but under a different name.   The generated output from Webpack:

```
<img _ngcontent-c1="" alt="Hipster" src="content/ca854e6d0785ba4b9d715049c0bdbcb3.png">
```

Comment: You are right. I forgot to add "content" in the path of my exemple (sorry), but I think the problem is elsewhere (webpack ?). I don't find my image in the target path even if the file name changed. I opened each PNG image generated in the target folder with an image viewer and I don't see my image...

Comment: Did you try adding `content` to the path? The example I gave works when added to home.component.html.  You also need to run webpack if you aren't already

Comment: Yes I try but it doesn't work. When I use `yarn start` command I can see in the log console `yarn run webpack:dev`. There is also a list of hashed files by `at-loader` and no error message.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your images in the assets folder and try to fetch from there like this -

```
<img scr="assets/images/hello.png" alt="hello the world">
```

Comment: Don't work because in JHispter environment there is no "assets" directory. The "assets" parameter in the ".angular-cli.json" file is  ["content", "i18n", "favicon.ico"].

Comment: In JHipster environment "content" directory is used to store static ressources. It is not the default configuration. No need to create another directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my JHipster environment, the only way I found was to add a selector to the `home.scss` file like this :

```
.hello {
    height: 150px;
    background: url("../../content/images/hello.png") no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

To show my image in a HTML template I used :
 
`<div class="hello" ></div>`

If I don't reference the image in the .scss file, the PNG image in the `webapp/content/image` is not copied to the `target/www/content` folder.

Are there other workarounds that are simpler to implement to display a static image in html template ?